# Rest Easy Client Framework value lost after unmarshaling

Tags: java, resteasy

Yesterday I tried to use the client side of the RestEasy framework. The interface has a method:

```
@PUT
@Path("document/autoincrement")
@Consumes("application/xml")
BaseClientResponse<String> insertPointOfInterest(PoiDocument poiDocument);
```

and the call to some (Jersey) rest service looks like:

```
    String restServerServiceUrl = "http://my.jersey.server/rest/serviceFoo/v1/";
    NSSClientService client = ProxyFactory.create(NSSClientService.class, restServerServiceUrl);

    PoiDocument poiDocument = new PoiDocument("Parkirišče", "90", 390262.85133115170, 42240.33558245482);

    BaseClientResponse<String> response = client.insertPointOfInterest(poiDocument);
    assert response.getResponseStatus() == Response.Status.OK;

    // Expected result
    //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><insertedRecord><record>14</record></insertedRecord>

    logger.info("Returned: " + response.getEntity());
```

And the logger prints:

14

Kind of expected.

But I want an object not a string, so I can easely assert the values returned. The interface:

```
@PUT
@Path("document/autoincrement")
@Consumes("application/xml")
BaseClientResponse<InsertedResponse> insertPointOfInterest(PoiDocument poiDocument);
```

Instead of String there is now a InsertedResponse class which looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="insertedRecord")
public class InsertedResponse extends ResponseResult{

    String insertedRecord;

    public InsertedResponse(int insertedRecord) {
        this.insertedRecord = Integer.toString(insertedRecord);
    }

    public InsertedResponse(){
        insertedRecord = "";
    }

    @XmlElement(name="record")
    public String getInsertedRecords(){
        return insertedRecord;
    }

    public void add(int recNo) {
        insertedRecord = Integer.toString(recNo);
    }
}
```

...and its superclass:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
public abstract class ResponseResult {

    protected String getClearString(String string) {

        if (string != null) {
            return Constants.removeInvalidXMLCharacters(string);

        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now, when I change the client call also to:

```
    BaseClientResponse<InsertedResponse> response = client.insertPointOfInterest(poiDocument);
    logger.info("Returned: " + response.getEntity().getInsertedRecords());
```

I get an empty string instead of some value.

So, the question is - where did the value of  go? It should print a number, like 14 in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One missing JAXB annotation (@XmlSeeAlso)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
@XmlSeeAlso( { InsertedResponse.class, OtherChild.class, SomeOtherChild.class })
public abstract class ResponseResult {

    ...
}
```

and an added setter method

```
@XmlRootElement(name="insertedRecord")
public class InsertedResponse extends ResponseResult{

    ...

    public void setInsertedRecords(String insertedRecord) {            
        this.insertedRecord = insertedRecord;
    }
```

solved the problem.